# Triggering an SSRS report when a database value evaluates to true

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I've been reading about 'Data Alerts' which is a feature that is available with SSRS and Sharepoint. I am wondering if something similar is available that would allow me to trigger the delivery of an SSRS report when a value within a database evaluated to true - I don't have Sharepoint and don't plan to install it.

Update:

One workaround I found was that you can create a schedule in SSRS for a report, then using the below query, you can find the associated SQL Agent Job for it.

```
SELECT *
FROM
ReportServer.dbo.[Subscriptions] Subscriptions
INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule R ON Subscriptions.SubscriptionID = R.SubscriptionID
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs J ON Convert(nvarchar(128),R.ScheduleID) = J.name
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules JS ON J.job_id = JS.job_id
```

One thing to note is that the name will look something like this '80B30DA6-6654-4639-82CD-F021E57D2604' you can then right click the agent job and disable it - you don't want it to run on the timed schedule you created within the SSRS subscription, because we want it to run based upon a data alert.

You can then create another SQL Agent job and base it upon a T-SQL statement, set your desired schedule to check the database. (Once a day, once a week, etc)

And then craft your SQL query to evaluate whether the conditon you want to check evaluates to true - placing it in your IF clause. 
When the IF becomes true call the msdb.dbo.sp_start_job function and sending it the Job name.

```
--Example 
DECLARE @MaxID int
SET @MaxID = (SELECT max(idcolumn) FROM DbaTools.dbo.TestTable)
IF @MaxID > 1

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'80B30DA6-6654-4639-82CD-F021E57D2604'
ELSE  
-- do nothing
```

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using? Is it Standard or Enterprise?

Comment: @harry SSRS 2017 - Standard as far as I know.

Comment: Hmm.. with enterprise, you can do data driven subscription.. checking db at regular intervals and triggering report based on result.. I'm not sure what you could do with standard!

Comment: @harry I've  updated my question with a workaround hack I've discovered.

Comment: Yeah.. that is one way you can do it.. So with enterprise, you can do it all in one place as it was meant to be.. but with standard.. you have to go this way. good luck